# Why glycosylation of a protein increases its non-specific binding properties?

Tags: protein-structure

This doubt arose while reading this website: https://www.thermofisher.com/cn/en/home/life-science/protein-biology/protein-biology-learning-center/protein-biology-resource-library/pierce-protein-methods/avidin-biotin-complex-method-ihc-detection.html

Comment: I think it has something to do with lectins binding to the glycosylated moiety.